# Closing space when hiding collectionview cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview, when i setHidden on a cell, i get a blank space. I need the remaining cells to bunch up and cover this gap, later on the hidden cell will be revealed again.

Is there a way to achieve this? I have tried setHidden and also setting height of the cell to 0 etc

Here is an image of the issue using [self setHidden:TRUE] on a cell, i can amend the post with code if there are specifics required. I want the grey gaps closed rather than this odd spacing

[image]

Comment: setHidden: TRUE will not definitely free up the space.Could you please post some code how are you laying out the cells in collectionview and calculating the cell size? Did you use extend UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout?

Answer (score 0):

This should be driven from your model layer - it's not enough to just hide the cell. Take a closer look at your `UICollectionViewDataSource` and specifically at `numberOfItemsInSection` and `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. These two methods should take care of showing the correct number (and kind) of cells, based on your model.

Comment: so when i hide a cell and unhide it i need to change the sections number? that could be tricky as i populate everything via delegate callbacks once the view has loaded so it doesnt know ahead of time what may need to be hidden

Comment: You can read the [Inserting and Deleting Rows and Sections](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html) section (it's for `UITableView` but you'll get the idea)